# What does "holy thing" refer to in Leviticus?

Tags: leviticus, word-study

In Leviticus 22:10 (and mentioned in a few other verses too) it says "...shall not eat of a holy thing..."

What does "holy thing" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## "Holy" = "Set Apart (for a Special Purpose)"

"Holy" ([qodesh, 6944](http://www.biblestudytools.com/lexicons/hebrew/nas/qodesh.html) קֹדֶשׁ ) means "set apart (for a special purpose)." Its synonyms, like "consecrated" and "sacred" mean the same thing.

In the context of Leviticus 22:10, God is speaking of **sacrifices.**

> be careful with the holy gifts of the sons of Israel, which they dedicate to Me

Many of the sacrifices that the Israelites were to make gave a portion to the priests and Levites. ([Ex 29](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/exodus/29.html), [Nu 18](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/numbers/18.html)) These were only to be eaten by (ceremonially clean) priests and levites. They were "holy" because they had been given to God.